# Thread in my fragment cannot run

Tags: android, multithreading

I write a fragment containing a recyclerview, which is used to display data from the Internet. However, I find that my `thread` in `getJSON` method does not run at all, and I cannot figure out how to deal with it.

[The screenshot of my debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI7Wr.png)

```
public class FragmentHot extends Fragment {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    refreshRecyclerView();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    private View mView;
    private List<Book> mBookList = new ArrayList<>();
    BookRecyclerViewAdapter mBookRecyclerViewAdapter;

    private void refreshRecyclerView() {
        mBookRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mBookList.size() - 1);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hot, container, false);
        initRecyclerView();
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getJSON();
    }

    private void getJSON() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URL url;
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("http://api.zhuishushenqi.com/cats/lv2/statistics");
                    inputStream = url.openStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                    JSONArray books = jsonObject.getJSONArray("books");
                    File externalFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File imageTemp = new File(externalFolder.getPath() + "/Reader/temp/cover");
                    if (!imageTemp.exists()) {
                        imageTemp.mkdirs();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObjectBook = books.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jsonObjectBook.getString("_id");
                        String title = jsonObjectBook.getString("title");
                        String author = jsonObjectBook.getString("author");
                        String shortIntro = jsonObjectBook.getString("shortIntro");
                        String cover = jsonObjectBook.getString("cover");
                        cover = URLDecoder.decode(cover);
                        String coverPath = imageTemp.getPath() + "/" +
                                id + ".jpg";
                        String site = jsonObjectBook.getString("site");
                        int banned = jsonObjectBook.getInt("banned");
                        int latelyFollower = jsonObjectBook.getInt("latelyFollower");
                        String retentionRatio = Integer.toString(jsonObjectBook.getInt
                                ("retentionRatio"));
                        Book book = new Book(id, title, author, shortIntro, cover, site, banned,
                                latelyFollower, retentionRatio);
                        book.setCoverPath(coverPath);
                        mBookList.add(book);
                    }
                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.what = 0;
                    mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_hot_recycler_view);
        mBookRecyclerViewAdapter = new BookRecyclerViewAdapter(mBookList,
                getActivity());
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mBookRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you find out thread in getJson() not working?

Comment: @Bek I have added a screenshot, the debugger tell me that.

Comment: is it throwing an error?

Comment: I think you're initializing your adapter before your thread has finished

Comment: below uploaded asynctask version check it

Comment: if you want to use thread then call initRecyclerView() after thread has finished inside handleMessage

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `sendMessage`

Something like this:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.what = 0;
message.obj = something;
mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

You should use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for such operations.

Comment: I have just added that line, but the thread in getJSON is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

replace thread with asynctask like below

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            initRecyclerView();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            URL url;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://api.zhuishushenqi.com/cats/lv2/statistics");
                inputStream = url.openStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                JSONArray books = jsonObject.getJSONArray("books");
                File externalFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File imageTemp = new File(externalFolder.getPath() + "/Reader/temp/cover");
                if (!imageTemp.exists()) {
                    imageTemp.mkdirs();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectBook = books.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObjectBook.getString("_id");
                    String title = jsonObjectBook.getString("title");
                    String author = jsonObjectBook.getString("author");
                    String shortIntro = jsonObjectBook.getString("shortIntro");
                    String cover = jsonObjectBook.getString("cover");
                    cover = URLDecoder.decode(cover);
                    String coverPath = imageTemp.getPath() + "/" +
                            id + ".jpg";
                    String site = jsonObjectBook.getString("site");
                    int banned = jsonObjectBook.getInt("banned");
                    int latelyFollower = jsonObjectBook.getInt("latelyFollower");
                    String retentionRatio = Integer.toString(jsonObjectBook.getInt
                            ("retentionRatio"));
                    Book book = new Book(id, title, author, shortIntro, cover, site, banned,
                            latelyFollower, retentionRatio);
                    book.setCoverPath(coverPath);
                    mBookList.add(book);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the method doInBackground cannot run, but onPostExecute does run.

Comment: It says `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: Did you give permissions to INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Yes, I have give the permission.

Comment: I find that when I delete the `initRecyclerView();` in `onCreateView()` and use it in handleMessage, my original Thread can run, it's so confusing.

Comment: I find the real problem is my poor capacity in debug, I ignore that the url is wrong and I put a brake on the `try {` line which cannot be brake, it makes me draw a wrong conclusion.

Comment: Also found out. Your jsonobject doesn't contain books array and it's throwing exception.

Comment: I'm sorry for disturb you for a long time, but thanks anyway for your patience.